# ZipException opening "xalan.jar"

Tags: java, ant, xalan, java-21

In order to migrate the codebase from jdk8 to jdk21, Getting below error during compile -

- ZipException opening "xalan.jar": ZIP file can't be opened as a file system because entry "/../classes/org/apache/xpath/compiler/Compiler.class" has a '.' or '..' element in its name*

I understand in recent versions of jdk, '.' and '..' is not allowed in the file name. And, I don't see any dot in xalan.jar file structure. Is /**..**/classes/org/apache/xpath/compiler/Compiler.class these dots are causing issue?
I am using ant to compile and build it.
Using xalan - 2.7.2, ant - 1.7.1 version.

I checked xalan file structure to find dot in the name. I also tried to upgrade it to later version.

Edit -

Here is the error log:-

```
 [javac] C:\source\com\admin\document\AdminDoc.java:1: error: cannot access com.admin.document

 [javac] package com.admin.document;

 [javac] ^

 [javac]   ZipException opening "xalan.jar": ZIP file can't be opened as a file system because entry  "/../classes/org/apache/xpath/compiler/Compiler.class" has a '.' or '..' element in its name

 [javac] 100 errors

 [javac] only showing the first 100 errors, of 779 total; use -Xmaxerrs if you would like to see more
```

Similarly, getting this error for all packages in the codebase.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Done! Please check. Getting this log for all packages in the codebase.

Comment: Probably a good idea to post (formatted as I've just formatted your error code) build.xml

Comment: To be precise, filenames can certainly have `.` and `..` segments.  But zip entry names cannot.

Comment: Do you even need xalan.jar in your classpath?